# How do I access blocks or templates defiend in a dependant helm chart from a parrent helm chart?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a helm chart for an application that uses the Bitnami  MongoDB chart (10.x)

```yaml
dependencies:
  - repository: https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
    name: mongodb
    version: ~10.28.2
```

I want to access MongoDB's chart's value `{{ include "mongodb.service.nameOverride" . }}`

However, when I use it in my parent chart.

```yaml
            - name: MONGO_HOST
              #value:  {{ include "mongodb.service.nameOverride" . }}
              value: maestro-maestro-mongodb-headless
```

I get the error:

```
[ERROR] templates/: template: foo/templates/services/deployment.yaml:36:26: executing "maestro/templates/services/deployment.yaml" at <include "mongodb.service.nameOverride" .>: error calling include: template: no template "mongodb.service.nameOverride" associated with template "gotpl"
```

I can not find any documentation on this.

Comment: You should be able to just call it; is it in fact listed as a dependency in your `Chart.yaml` or `requirements.yaml` file?  (Note that the `.` parameter to the template will be different in parent vs. child chart context as well, but that shouldn't affect whether the template is visible.)

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor I was not able to figure out ho access the child values, however I was luck to be using well-made child chart, so I was able to set a service name override in my values.yaml and then use that.

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor I don't consider my workaround an answer for the question. I just got lucky with a workaround on my particular sub chart.

Comment: check [Importing Child Values via dependencies](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#importing-child-values-via-dependencies), maybe it will help

Comment: @Vit, on first glance, that just allows me to override how I reference the sub charts values. What I want to do as access the default values (and _helpers, in my parent chart without an override. However, I will try it)